# How to store a function's return argument in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I intend to use the return type of the third argument of `withResponse` for another function `brRead`. I get this error:

> parse error on input `)' Failed, modules loaded: none.

From the following code(using [Network.HTTP.Client](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.28/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html)):

```
startOn url = do
    man <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
    req <- parseUrl url
    withResponse req man (let x = return (withResponse req man))
    brRead x
    return $ read
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include more code? The most likely cause of this is a bad type signature, but without seeing more code it's difficult to be sure *which* signature's at the root of the problem.

Comment: it's the `resp` in this line - this is supposed to be an action *processing* this `Response BodyReader` (a function from this to some `IO a`) - but you only give it the response (**you** have to create the actual `content` here) - for example `content <- withResponse req man (\resp -> return "What")` should work (but is not what you wont most likely) - btw: you don't need either the `resonseOpen` or then `withResponse` - go with one of them

Comment: Thanks for the input, however, the third argument needs some `(Response BodyReader -> IO a)`, not some string.. which is seemingly difficult to produce here.

Comment: yes of course - the idea of `withResponse` is that it will fetch the resonponse from the `req` for you (using a connection obtained from `mng`) - once it got the response it will feed it to the function/action *you have to provide* in the thirds parameter and feed the output of this back - it's a high-level way to let you only be concerned with the `Response Body`

Comment: Well I got a workaround by changing `resp <- responseOpen req man` to `let resp = responseOpen req man`. I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Carsten I get what you were implying in your first comment. Namely I could have `content <- withResponse req man (\resp -> return responseOpen req man)`

Comment: but this would be really strange ... why would you ignore the `resp` the function fetched for you and *refetch* it - isn't `withResponse req man return` what you want then?

Comment: Well I'm just not sure what syntax to use to achieve that.

Comment: Does this make sense? `content <- withResponse req man >>= withResponse`

Comment: I believe this is what I need: `content <- withResponse req man (\x -> return (withResponse req man))`

Comment: I believe it's getting worse ... maybe you should edit your question and explain what you want with the response

Comment: Leaving aside type errors and the nested `withResponse`s, are you looking for something like `do ... let x = withResponse req man; withResponse req man x ...`?

Comment: Yes, I want something like that. The problem is that withResponse is wrapped with IO in the first call, so as a result I get this: `Couldn't match type 'Response BodyReader -> IO a0' with 'Response BodyReader'`

Comment: Since you're already in `do` notation for `IO`, you can use `do ... x <- withResponse req man; withResponse req man x ...`. Note, however, that `withResponse` takes 3 arguments and you are giving the first one 2 arguments. You may want to give a third argument to the first call, or use a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused and it's going to take a bit to unpack this.

While there is a generic way to sneak the input parameter out when you're working inside the `IO` monad using `IORef`s, I'm not going to tell you that because:

1. It isn't necessary to do anything sneaky because the return value of `withResponse` is what its third parameter returns anyway.
2. It wouldn't help you, because if you take the `Response BodyReader` out of `withResponse`, it will be closed and you won't be able to read it.

First off, the type of `withResponse` is this:

```
withResponse :: Request -> Manager -> (Response BodyReader -> IO a) -> IO a
```

Now, the [description of `withResponse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.28/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:withResponse) makes it clear that the `Response BodyReader` object is only valid inside the action of `withResponse`. So if you try to take that object out of `withResponse` as you're asking to, you won't be able to read it. The `Response BodyReader` object will already be closed.

Instead, what you're supposed to do is create a function that uses the response and does something with it, and pass that function. Since all you claim to want to do is call `brRead` on the response a single time, you could do this:

```
startOn url = do
    man <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
    req <- parseUrl url
    read <- withResponse req man (brRead . responseBody)
    return $ read
```

That will return to you only the first `ByteString` chunk of the given URL, but if that's all you need, that's fine. If what you're trying to do here is return the whole `ByteString` of a response, there's already a convenience function for that - `httpLbs`:

```
startOn url = do
    man <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
    req <- parseUrl url
    response <- httpLbs req man
    return $ responseBody response
```